# In Keras library, what is the meaning of "nb_steps_warmup" in the DQNAgent Object initialization?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I can't understand the meaning of "nb_steps_warmup", a parameter of the `__init__` function of DQNAgent class of the Keras_RL module.

I just know that when I set small value for "nb_steps_warmup" the command line prints: `UserWarning: Not enough entries to sample without replacement. Consider increasing your warm-up phase to avoid oversampling!`

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import gym
import gym_briscola
import argparse
import os

from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation, Flatten
from keras.optimizers import Adam

from rl.agents.dqn import DQNAgent
from rl.policy import BoltzmannQPolicy
from rl.memory import SequentialMemory
import logging


def getModel(input_shape, nb_actions):

    # Next, we build a very simple model.
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Flatten(input_shape = input_shape))
    model.add(Dense(nb_actions, activation = 'relu'))
    for i in range(2):
        model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'relu'))

    model.add(Dense(nb_actions, activation = 'relu'))
    # print(model.summary())
    return model

def init():

    ENV_NAME = 'Briscola-v0'

    # Get the environment and extract the number of actions.
    env = gym.make(ENV_NAME)
    env.setName("Inteligence")
    env.cicle = True
    nb_actions = env.action_space.n
    window_length = 10

    input_shape = (window_length, 5)

    # Finally, we configure and compile our agent. You can use every built-in Keras optimizer and
    # even the metrics!
    memory = SequentialMemory(limit=50000, window_length=window_length)

    #Maxwell-boltzmann distribution
    policy = BoltzmannQPolicy()
    dqn = DQNAgent(model=getModel(input_shape, nb_actions), nb_actions=nb_actions, memory=memory, nb_steps_warmup=11,
                   target_model_update=1e-5, policy=policy, dueling_type='avg', enable_dueling_network=True)

    print("Compila")
    dqn.compile(Adam(lr=1e-5), metrics=['mae'])

    try:
        dqn.load_weights('dqn_{}_weights.h5f'.format(ENV_NAME))
    except OSError:
        print("File non trovato")

    return dqn, env, ENV_NAME

def startTraining():

    dqn, env, ENV_NAME = init()

    print("Fit")
    dqn.fit(env, nb_steps=5E6, visualize=False, verbose=1, log_interval=1000)

    # After training is done, we save the final weights.
    dqn.save_weights('dqn_{}_weights.h5f'.format(ENV_NAME), overwrite=True)


def startTest():

    dqn, env, _ = init()

    print("Test")
    # Finally, evaluate our algorithm for 5 episodes.
    dqn.test(env, nb_episodes=10, visualize=False)

#Log config
def setLogging(show = True):
    logging.getLogger("Briscola").propagate = show
    logging.getLogger("IA").propagate = True
    logging.getLogger("Client").propagate = show
    logging.getLogger("Vincitore").propagate = show

    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #Parameter settings
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-m", "--modality", help="The modality of the program", const="train", nargs='?')
    parser.add_argument("-l", "--logging", help="Enable logging", type=bool, const=False, nargs='?')
    args = parser.parse_args()

    setLogging(True)
    print("Avvio modalita' ", args.modality)

    if args.modality == "test":
        startTest()
    else:
        startTraining()

    print("Fine")
```

This is the doc of the module: https://keras-rl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/agents/dqn/

I hope I was clear with my English.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Often times in reinforcement learning the error rate of the first few steps will be very large and may cause your parameters to oscillate. This is usually attributed to the lack of specificity of the deeper layers in your network. Thus we can come up with some schemes where the learning rate changes in a pre-determined way. For example we can use constant warm-up or gradual warm-up.

The convergence of stochastic gradient descent is a function of the learning rate and the batch size. When the batch size is increased too much then the needed increase in the learning rate can be such that it is beyond the possible curvature of the loss function. We thus introduce warm up as a means by which we can introduce large learning rates without the instability.